# asp.net form control ID is null on enumeration

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a simple ASP.Net page, and I am enumerating through the controls doing things to the controls via reflection (localising the page - but that is whole other can of managerial dictat type worms). So...I have a test page thus:

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Master Pages/Root.master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="refelectiontest.aspx.cs" Inherits="refelectiontest" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" Runat="Server">

    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" />

    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label><asp:Label ID="Label2"
        runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>

    <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>

</asp:Content>
```

And then in the code behind, I want to iterate through the controls...

So I have this (the master page can deal with itself)

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {

            try
            {

                foreach (Control ctrl in Form.Controls)
                {
                    if (ctrl is ContentPlaceHolder)
                    {
                        ContentPlaceHolder chp = ctrl as ContentPlaceHolder;
                        foreach (Control control in chp.Controls)
                        {
                string strID = control.ID;
                //do stuff based on the the ID
                        }
                    }


                }

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Response.Write(ex.ToString());
            }
        }

    }
```

Now, if I just run this, it barfs with an object null exception. And if I step through the code, putting a breakpoint on the control.ID line, then indeed the ID is null. However, if I then expand the control object, the ID fills itself out and all is well.

It looks like the ID is only getting completed at the last moment - how can I ensure that I can get the ID without getting null?
The same thing happens if I don't use the master page.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this would be of any help, but you can use control.UniqueID. It works for me just fine, and I had the same bug and it was troubling me for hours.
Here is the code how it should look like according to me:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {

        try
        {

            foreach (Control ctrl in Form.Controls)
            {
                if (ctrl is ContentPlaceHolder)
                {
                    ContentPlaceHolder chp = ctrl as ContentPlaceHolder;
                    foreach (Control control in chp.Controls)
                    {
            string strID = control.UniqueID;
            //do stuff based on the the ID
                    }
                }


            }

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Response.Write(ex.ToString());
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try this?

```
        Response.ClearContent();
        Response.ClearHeaders();
        Response.ContentType = "text/plain";

        foreach (Control ctrl in this.Form.Controls)
        {
            //Response.Write("ID: " + ctrl.ID + "\n");
            //Response.Write("ClientID: " + ctrl.ClientID + "\n");
            if ((ctrl as ContentPlaceHolder) != null)
            {
                ContentPlaceHolder chp = ctrl as ContentPlaceHolder;
                Response.Write("Content Found" + "\n");
                foreach (Control control in chp.Controls)
                {
                    string strID = control.ID;
                    Response.Write("Control in content: " + strID + "\n");
                    //do stuff based on the the ID
                }
            }
        }
        Response.End();`
```

That code output the ID inside the ContentPlaceHolder. Some of them is empty, so you need to filter it.

Hope this helps

Comment: `if ((ctrl as ContentPlaceHolder) != null)`? Really?

Comment: Yes, tried that. It was still getting null IDs. My workaround was to ensure that I checked for null before doing something with the ID - turns out that the IDs of all of my objects were valid.

Answer (score 0):

I notice that the content container's `runat="server"` tag is not all lowercase. I don't know that it matters, but it could be case sensitive. Here's the MSDN page: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms529174%28v=vs.85%29.aspx